# Using a button to display the outcome of a coin flip Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple coinflip that outputs a certain image, for example in this case it is ctflip and tflip based on whether its true or false. When I press the button I want ti to run the coinFlip function to generate the number and then display the correct image.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>My Web Page</h1>
    <p>My paragraph.</p>
    <p id="flipDisplay"></p>
    <button onclick="coinFlip()"+"display()">Flip the Coin!</button>
    <script>
    function coinFlip() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    }
    function display() {
    if (coinFlip()) {
        document.write('<img src="./tflip.png">');
    }
    else {document.write('<img src="./ctflip.png">');
    }
    }
    </script>
    <!--<a><img src=javacript:flip></a> -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Okay so you asked a question and then provided some code. What is the problem? Does the code not do what you want it to do? On very first inspection I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for calling two functions is incorrect.  Only calling display should work fine here, because display calls coinflip itself.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>My Web Page</h1>
    <p>My paragraph.</p>
    <p id="flipDisplay"></p>
    <button onclick="display()">Flip the Coin!</button>
    <script>
      function coinFlip() {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
      }
      function display() {
        if (coinFlip()) {
          document.write('<img src="./tflip.png">');
        } else {
          document.write('<img src="./ctflip.png">');
        }
      }
    </script>
    <!--<a><img src=javacript:flip></a> -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

The proper syntax for calling two functions is `onClick="first();second();"` but it is often better to just call one function that calls others as needed.

Comment: this is incorrect, you most certainly can call two functions in one onclick event, they just need to be separated by semi colons

Comment: Gotcha, edited.  That doesn't change the fact that the call to coinFlip is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<button onClick="handleButtonClick();">Flip Coin</button>
```

JS:

```
function handleButtonClick() {
    coinFlip();
    display();
}
```

It is generally cleaner to map your HTML controls to a single point of entry in terms of script code. So that one logical action by the user leads to a single logical piece of functionality clearly described by the function name. Makes for more succinct, maintainable code.

In your specific example however, you do not require to call both functions. You already call the coinFlip function from within your display function. So, all you really need to call is display(), in fact.

Comment: why bother with this when he can call both function in the onclick?

Comment: read the display function -- the two function calls here are totally unnecessary

Comment: my bad you're right, so better answer, just call that one!

Comment: @Omarjmh Because it's cleaner and simpler to maintain.

Comment: Please add your reasoning to the answer itself. Comments are ephemeral. Also, your answer was indicated as a Low Quality Post since it  is mostly code with little explanation of how it helps the OP.

Comment: Amended to illustrate reasoning and some additional assistance. Thanks for your feedback :)